# Where does a Git branch start and what is its length?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

Every now and then I'm asked, on what commit a certain branch on git starts or if a certain commit has been created on a specific branch. The end point of a branch is pretty clear: that's where the branch label sits. But - where did it start? The trivial answer would be: on that commit where we *created* that branch. But that information is, as far as I know now, and that's why I'm asking the question, lost after the first commits.

As long as we know the commit where we branched off, we can draw the graph to make it clear:

```
A - B - C - - - - J     [master]
     \
      D - E - F - G     [branch-A]
           \
            H - - I     [branch-B]
```

I've created branch-B at commit `E` so that's the "start". I know that, because I did it. But can others recognize it the same way? We could draw the same graph like that:

```
A - B - C - - - - J     [master]
     \
      \       F - G     [branch-A]
       \     /
        D - E
             \
              H - I     [branch-B]
```

So, looking at the graph now, which branch started at `E`, which one at `B`? Is commit `D` a member of both branches or can we clearly decide whether it belongs to branch-A or branch-B?

This sounds somewhat philosophical but it really isn't. Supervisors sometimes like to know, when a branch has been started (it usually marks the start of a task) and to which branch some changes belong to (to get the purpose of some change - was it required for the work) and I'd like to know if git offers infos (tools, commands) or definitions to answer those questions correctly.

Comment: I think branches don't have a starting commit other than the first commit ever of the main branch. IMO all your branches start at commit `A`.

Comment: in your example branch A must have started at D (i.e. the first diversion from master), not E...

Comment: ObTroll: in Mercurial, the necessary information is captured in the commit which creates the branch, so this question is trivial to answer. But not in Git, sadly.

Comment: @muratgu Not necessarily - perhaps `branch-B` was created from `B` and first committed `D`, and then `branch-A` was created from `E` and first committed `F`... The graph alone is ambiguous...

Comment: @TomAnderson counter-troll: in Mercurial, you ***have to make commits*** to create branches?  Bummer...

Comment: @Andreas_D maybe the question you should be asking is where one branch currently diverges from another, instead of trying to figure out where they "started"?  I think [twalberg's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17581408/456814) is pretty interesting too.  Also, since you could easily `rebase` branches onto just about any point of a Git commit tree, what does it mean for a branch to "start" anywhere, really? I'm actually not sure myself :/

Comment: You want to get really trippy? Git allows you to have more than one root commit. So what happens when you have two completely separate trees, and then decide to merge them? Your branches would then literally start from two different points!

Comment: Want to get even more trippy? What if you have branch `X` based off a `develop` branch, and `develop` gets merged into `master` without `X` being re-integrated into the others yet?  Which branch is `X` "based off of"?  Two branches at once!?!?

Comment: @Cupcake: Dooh! I'll get you next time! Although i'm not sure what you're going to do with your branch with no commits in it. Some kind of zen version control?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Find common ancestor of two branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/find-common-ancestor-of-two-branches).

Comment: See also [Finding a branch point with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git).

Comment: @CodeGnome - I was not interested in common ancestors. That is a different and easy to solve task.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In Git, you could say that every branch starts at the root commit, and that would be quite literally true.  But I guess that's not very helpful for you.  What you could do instead is to define "the start of a branch" in relation to other branches.  One way you can do this is to use

```
git show-branch branch1 branch2 ... branchN
```

and that will show you the common commit between all specified branches at the bottom of the output (if there is, in fact, a common commit).

Here's an example from [the Linux Kernel Git documentation for `show-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-branch.html)

```
$ git show-branch master fixes mhf
* [master] Add 'git show-branch'.
 ! [fixes] Introduce "reset type" flag to "git reset"
  ! [mhf] Allow "+remote:local" refspec to cause --force when fetching.
---
  + [mhf] Allow "+remote:local" refspec to cause --force when fetching.
  + [mhf~1] Use git-octopus when pulling more than one heads.
 +  [fixes] Introduce "reset type" flag to "git reset"
  + [mhf~2] "git fetch --force".
  + [mhf~3] Use .git/remote/origin, not .git/branches/origin.
  + [mhf~4] Make "git pull" and "git fetch" default to origin
  + [mhf~5] Infamous 'octopus merge'
  + [mhf~6] Retire git-parse-remote.
  + [mhf~7] Multi-head fetch.
  + [mhf~8] Start adding the $GIT_DIR/remotes/ support.
*++ [master] Add 'git show-branch'.
```

In that example, `master` is being compared with the `fixes` and `mhf` branches. Think of this output as a table, with each branch represented by its own column, and each commit getting its own row. Branches that contain a commit will have a `+` or `-` show up in their column in the row for that commit.

At the very bottom of the output, you'll see that all 3 branches share a common ancestor commit, and that it is in fact the `head` commit of `master`:

```
*++ [master] Add 'git show-branch'.
```

This means that both `fixes` and `mhf` were branched off of that commit in `master`.

**Alternative solutions**

Of course that's only 1 possible way to determine a common base commit in Git.  Other ways include `git merge-base` to find common ancestors, and `git log --all --decorate --graph --oneline` or `gitk --all` to visualize the branches and see where they diverge (though if there are a lot of commits that becomes difficult very quickly).

**Other questions from original poster**

As for these questions you had:

> Is commit `D` a member of both branches or can we clearly decide whether it belongs to `branch-A` or `branch-B`?

`D` is a member of both branches, it's an ancestor commit for both of them.

> Supervisors sometimes like to know, ***when a branch has been started (it usually marks the start of a task)***...

In Git, you can rewrite the history of the entire commit tree(s) and their branches, so ***when*** a branch "starts" is not as set in stone as in something like TFS or SVN.  You can `rebase` branches onto any point in time in a Git tree, even putting it before the root commit!  Therefore, you can use it to "start" a task at any point in time in the tree that you want.

This is a common use case for `git rebase`, to sync branches up with the latest changes from an upstream branch, to push them "forward" in time along the commit graph, as if you had "just started" working on the branch, even though you've actually been working on it for a while.  You could even push branches back in time along the commit graph, if you wanted to (though you might have to resolve a lot of conflicts, depending on the branch contents...or maybe you won't).  You could even insert or delete a branch from right in the middle of your development history (though doing so would probably change the commit shas of a lot of commits).  Rewriting history is one of the primary features of Git that makes it so powerful and flexible.

This is why commits come with both an authored date (when the commit was originally authored), and a committed date (when the commit was last committed to the commit tree).  You can think of them as analogous to create time-date and last-modified time-date.

> Supervisors sometimes like to know...***to which branch some changes belong to*** (to get the purpose of some change - was it required for the work).

Again, because Git allows you to rewrite history, you can (re)base a set of changes on pretty much any branch/commit in the commit graph that you want.  `git rebase` literally allows you to move your entire branch around freely (though you might need to resolve conflicts as you go, depending on where you move the branch to and what it contains).

That being said, one of the tools you can use in Git to determine which branches or tags contains a set of changes is the `--contains`:

```
# Which branches contains commit X?
git branch --all --contains X

# Which tags contains commit X?
git tag --contains X
```

Comment: I should also mention that if you're using [GitHub Flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html) for your workflow, this question becomes trivial: all branches were diverged from some commit on `master`.  You could even `rebase` a branch to go right on top of `master`.

Comment: So it looks like git "only" provides *branch labels* but does not care about *branches* as we often see them: a list of commits with a first and a last one. Which is not bad at all: it gives us a great flexibility. But if we want to track *branches* (start, content, end,...) then we obviously have either organize the repository strictly or track them outside of the repo.

Comment: @Andreas_D I added more to answer for how to see which branches/tags contains a set of changes, hope that helps.

Comment: `git branch` doesn't have an `--all` option (tested on git version 1.7.4.4); a simple `git branch --contains X` (without `--all`) seems to work.

Comment: W.r.t your analogy for the author/committor date: I would compare the AuthorDate to the last modification time (`st_mtime`) and the CommitDate to the last status change time (`st_ctime`). Because when you move a file or rename it, its `st_mtime` stays the same but its `st_ctime` changes, just as when you rebase a commit, its AuthorDate stays unchanged but its CommitDate changes.

Comment: @musiphil the `--all` option to `git branch` was added in [version 1.7.8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/171edcbb49df30bbe96cc7f7204549df22c1beee). The short form, `-a`, has been available since [version 1.5.0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bfcc921430423828233dadfe274802ae68900f6e). You can double-verify this by checking [the blame of the `git branch` documentation file](https://github.com/git/git/blame/master/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L128-129).

Comment: Would it be so hard for git to track the history of commits for each branch, then show it just like it shows the ordinary commit history?  That is to say: branch-B's history goes all the way back to commit A, but that doesn't mean branch-B ever pointed at commit A--it didn't, and we users might like to know that.

Comment: So that I might see where a branch started from, so that I can remember why and who started it and plan what we're doing as a team.

Comment: @Patrick That's not really the job of the VCS, is it? Anyway, Git can already show you the point of divergence.

Comment: We can find divergence using `git show-branch` but in our workflow where feature branch (created from master branch) goes back in the master and then more development/fixes start and then goes back in the master and so on. So how to find the first divergence?

Answer (score 14):

The bounty notice on this question asks,

> I'd be interested in knowing whether or not thinking about Git branches as having a defined "beginning" commit other than the root commit even makes sense?

It kind of does except:

- the root commit is "the first commit *accessible* from the branch HEAD" (and don't forget there can be *multiple* root commit with [**orphan** branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/6309), used for instance in [GitHub for `gh-pages`](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/))
- I prefer considering the start of a branch being the commit of *another* branch from which said branch has been created ([tobib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035344/6309)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035344/6309) without the `~1`), or (simpler) the [**common ancestor**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549156/6309).
  (also in "[Finding a branch point with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527234/6309)", even though the [OP mentioned being not interested in common ancestors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581026/branch-length-where-does-a-branch-start-in-git/33050533#comment25689658_17581026)):

  ```
  git merge-base A master
  ```

That means:

- the first definition gives you a **fixed commit** (which might never change except in case of massive `filter-branch`)
- the second definition gives you a **relative commit** (relative to *another* branch) which can change at any time (the other branch can be deleted)

The second one makes more sense for git, which is all about merge and rebase between branches.

> Supervisors sometimes like to know, when a branch has been started (it usually marks the start of a task) and to which branch some changes belong to (to get the purpose of some change - was it required for the work)

Branches are simply the wrong marker for that: due to the transient nature of branches (which can be renamed/moved/rebased/deleted/...), you cannot mimick a "change set" or an "activity" with a branch, to represent a "task".

That is an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): the OP is asking for an attempted *solution* (where does a branch starts) rather than the *actual problem* (what could be considered a task in Git).

To do that (representing a task), you could use:

- *tags*: they are immutable (once associated to a commit, that commit is no longer supposed to move/be rebased), and any commits between two well-named tags can represent an activity.
- some [`git notes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) to a commit to memorize to which "work item" said commit has been created (contrary to tags, notes can be rewritten if the commit is amended or rebased).
- hooks (to associate a commit to some "external" object like a "work item", based on the commit message). That is what the [bridge Git-RTC -- IBM Rational Team Concert -- does with a pre-receive hook](https://jazz.net/library/article/854))
  The point is: the start of a branch does not always reflect the start of a task, but merely the continuation of an history which can change, and whom sequence should represent a logical set of changes.

Comment: I think the issue tracker should contain the information about when did we begin a task. That's why we use #task-id in the commits. I don't think getting the date from the commits would help. In most cases we start a task with user story, use cases, etc... there is a lot of work before writing code. So I think the question does not make sense.

Comment: @inf3rno I agree. The bridge git-RTC only maintains a simple link in order to add the git commit in the RTC change set, associated to a work item which contains all the information.

Comment: Thank you very much VonC, this is *exactly* the kind of answer I was hoping to get with my bounty! It is somewhat of a high-level question, and your answer discussed it on an equally high-level. Your explanation about how representing work tasks with Git branches is inconvenient is very enlightening indeed, and definitely helps me better understand the nature of branches in Git, and how they relate to developer workflows.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you are asking the wrong question. IMO, it doesn't make sense to ask where a branch starts since a given branch includes all changes made to every file **ever** (i.e. since the initial commit).

On the other hand, asking where two branches diverged is definitely a valid question. In fact, this seems to be exactly what you want to know. In other words, you don't really want to know information about a single branch. Instead you want to know some information about comparing two branches.

A little bit of research turned up [the gitrevisions man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) which describes the details of referring to specific commits and ranges of commits. In particular,

> To exclude commits reachable from a commit, a prefix ^ notation is used. E.g. ^r1 r2 means commits reachable from r2 but exclude the ones reachable from r1.
>
> This set operation appears so often that there is a shorthand for it. When you have two commits r1 and r2 (named according to the syntax explained in SPECIFYING REVISIONS above), you can ask for commits that are reachable from r2 excluding those that are reachable from r1 by ^r1 r2 and it can be written as r1..r2.

So, using the example from your question, you can get the commits where `branch-A` diverges from `master` with

```
git log master..branch-A
```

Comment: To be clear, `git log master..branch-A` will only tell you the commits that exist in `branch-A` but that don't yet exist in `master`.  This doesn't necessarily indicate by itself that `branch-A` was "branched off of master", does it? What if you have a `develop` branch, "branched off of master", and `branch-A` was "branched off of develop"?  Wouldn't `git log master..branch-A` then  show all changes in `branch-A` not in `master`, including other commits in `develop`?

Comment: But .. `git log master..branch-B` would show a similiar result, right? Although, in the examples reality, branch-B didn't diverge from master but from branch-A. So it would work only if I new, that branch-A diverged from branch-B. And not the other way round!?

Comment: @Andreas_D you need to number the branches, or number the commits. Using letters for both is getting really confusing.

Comment: @Cupcake oops, you're right. But I think it's to late now. If I change either branch names or commits NOW, all answers and comments will be confusing :( Next question, better approach

Comment: @Andreas_D regarding the whole `branch-A` vs `branch-B` thing, you're not asking the right questions with Git.  "`branch-A` diverged from `branch-B`" or "`branch-B` diverged from `branch A`" are meaningless.

Comment: @Cupcake Yes, `git log master..branch-A` shows the commits which are in `branch-A` but not in `master`. This directly addresses the example that the OP explains in the last paragraph starting at "Supervisors sometimes like to know...". In souch a situation, the supervisor wants to know about all of the relevant commits, not just the commit where the branches diverge.

Comment: @Cupcake - not for the people that ask the questions - they're in fact interesting in keeping record of the fact that "branch_B" has been started on commit E (speaking of a remote repo where the history is never rewritten). For whatever reasons.

Answer (score 10):

There are two separate concerns here.  Starting from your example,

> ```
> A - B - C - - - - J     [master]
>      \
>       \       F - G     [branch-A]
>        \     /
>         D - E
>              \
>               H - I     [branch-B]
> ```
>
> [...] Supervisors sometimes like to know, when a branch has been started (it usually marks the start of a task) and to which branch some changes belong (to get the purpose of some change - was it required for the work)

two factual observations before we get to the meat:

First observation: what your supervisor wants to know is the mapping between commits and some external workorder-ish record: what commits address bug-43289 or featureB?  Why are we changing `strcat` usage in `longmsg.c`?  Who's going to pay for the twenty hours between your previous push and this one? The branch names themselves don't matter here, what matters is the commits' relationships with external administrative records.

Second observation: whether `branch-A` or `branch-B` gets published first (via say merge or rebase or push), the work in commits D and E has to go with it right then  and not be duplicated by any subsequent operation. It makes no difference at all what was current when those commits were made.  Branch names don't matter here, either. What matters is commits' relations with each other via the ancestry graph.

---

So my answer is, so far as any history is concerned branch names don't matter at all.  They're convenience tags showing which commit is current for some purpose specific to that repo, nothing more.  If you want some useful moniker in the default merge-commit message subject line, `git branch some-useful-name` the tip before merging, and merge that.  They're the same commits either way.

Tying whatever branch name the developer had checked out at the time of commit with some external record -- or anything at all -- is deep into "all fine so long as everything works" territory.  Don't Do It.  Even with the restricted usage common in most VCS's, your `D-E-{F-G,H-I}` will occur sooner rather than later, and then your branch naming conventions will have to be adapted to handle that, and then something more complicated will show up, . . .

Why bother?  Put the report number(s) prompting the work in a tagline at the bottom of your commit messages and be done with it.  `git log --grep` (and git in general) is blazingly fast for good reason.

Even a fairly flexible prep hook to insert taglines like this is trivial:

```sh
branch=`git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD`                     # branch name if any
workorder=`git config branch.${branch:+$branch.}x-workorder`  # specific or default config
tagline="Acme-workorder-id: ${workorder:-***no workorder supplied***}"
sed -i "/^ *Acme-workorder-id:/d; \$a$tagline" "$1"
```

and here's the basic pre-receive hook loop for when you need to inspect every commit:

```sh
while read old new ref; do              # for each pushed ref
        while read commit junk; do      # check for bad commits

                # test here, e.g. 
                git show -s $commit | grep -q '^ *Acme-workorder-id: ' \
                || { rc=1; echo commit $commit has no workorder associated; }
                # end of this test

        done <<EOD
        $(git rev-list $old..$new)
EOD
done
exit $rc
```

The kernel project uses taglines like this for copyright signoff and code-review recording.  It really couldn't get much simpler or more robust.

<sup><sup>Note that I did some hand-mangling after c&p to de-specialize real scripts. Keyboard-to-editbox warning</sup></sup>

Comment: " Put the report number(s) prompting the work in a tagline at the bottom of your commit messages and be done with it.". I agree, and that is generally how any type of git-task tracking system starts. +1

Comment: @VonC Thanks. Yeah, we're all trying to say the same thing, just like everybody else who's ever had a whack at answering this for newbies.  Trying to discuss every detail of why OP's question is misguided would take pages and nobody'd read it.  What exactly is going to light the bulb for anybody probably just boils down to time-on-task, but ennh, it's worth trying to state things clearly just for yourself, yeah?

Answer (score 9):

I think this is probably a good opportunity for education. `git` doesn't really record the starting point of any branch. Unless the reflog for that branch still contains the creation record, there's no way to definitively determine where it started, and if the branch has merges in it anywhere, it may in fact have more than one root commit, as well as many different possible points where it might have been created and started to diverge from its original source.

It might be a good idea to ask a counter question in such cases - why do you need to know where it branched from, or does it matter in any useful way where it branched from? There might or might not be good reasons that this is important - many of the reasons are probably tied up in the specific workflow your team has adopted and is trying to enforce, and may indicate areas where your workflow might be improved in some way. Perhaps one improvement would be figuring out what the "right" questions to ask - for example, rather than "where did `branch-B` branch from", maybe "what branches do or don't contain the fixes/new features introduced by `branch-B`"...

I'm not sure that a completely satisfactory answer to this question really exists...

Answer (score 6):

As @cupcake explained, there is no starting point of a branch. You can only check where one branch first touched another one. This is probably what you wnat in most cases. @code-guru already explained the syntax to refer to ranges of commits.

Putting it all together: This command shows the first commit before the first commit that was in `branch-A` but not in `master`:

`` git show `git rev-list branch-A ^master --topo-order | tail -n 1`~1 ``

Comment: Gives me `zsh: not enough directory stack entries.`. Note, my branch name contains a slash.

Answer (score 6):

From a philosophical point of view, the question of a branch's history cannot be answered in a global sense.  However, the [`reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) does track each branch's history **in that particular repository**.

Thus, if you have a single central repository that everyone pushes to, you can use its `reflog` to track this information (some more details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876206/how-do-i-view-a-git-repos-receive-history)).  First, on that central repository, ensure the reflog is recorded and never gets cleaned out:

```
$ git config core.logAllRefUpdates true
$ git config gc.reflogExpire never
```

Then you can run `git reflog <branchname>` to inspect the branch's history.

#### Example

I reproduced your sample commit graph with a few pushes into a test repository.  Now I can do this sort of thing:

```
$ git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate
* 64c393b (branch-b) commit I
* feebd2f commit H
| * 3b9dbb6 (branch-a) commit G
| * 18835df commit F
|/  
* d3840ca commit E
* b25fd0b commit D
| * 8648b54 (master) commit J
| * 676e263 commit C
|/  
* 17af0d2 commit B
* bdbfd6a commit A

$ git reflog --date=local master branch-a branch-b
64c393b branch-b@{Sun Oct 11 21:45:03 2015}: push
3b9dbb6 branch-a@{Sun Oct 11 21:45:17 2015}: push
18835df branch-a@{Sun Oct 11 21:43:32 2015}: push
8648b54 master@{Sun Oct 11 21:42:09 2015}: push
17af0d2 master@{Sun Oct 11 21:41:29 2015}: push
bdbfd6a master@{Sun Oct 11 21:40:58 2015}: push
```

So you can see that in my example, when `branch-a` first came into existence, it was pointed at commit `F`, and that a second push to the central server moved it forward to commit `G`.  Whereas when `branch-b` first came into existence, it was pointed at commit `I`, and it hasn't seen any updates yet.

#### Caveats

This shows only the history **as it was pushed to the central repo**.  If for example a coworker started `branch-A` at commit `A`, but then rebased it onto commit `B` before pushing it, that information would not be reflected in the central repository's reflog.

This also doesn't provide a definitive record of **where a branch began**.  We can't really say for sure which branch "owns" commits `D` and `E` that initially forked off of master.  Did they get created on `branch-a` and then picked up by `branch-b`, or the other way around?

Both branches initially appeared on the central repository containing those commits, and the `reflog` does tell us which branch showed up on the central repository first.  However, these commits may have been "passed around" amongst several end-user repositories, via `format-patch`, etc.  So even though we know which branch pointer was responsible for carrying them to the central server first, we don't know their **ultimate origin**.

Answer (score 6):

#### Some architectural details

Git stores the revisions to a repository as a series of commits.  These commits contain a link to information about the changes to the files since the last commit and, importantly, a link to the previous commit.  In broad terms a branch's commit history is a singly linked list from the most recent revision all the way back to the repository's root. The state of the repository at any commit is that commit combined with all the commits prior to it all the way back to the root.

So what's the HEAD? And what's a branch?

The HEAD is a special pointer to the newest commit in the currently active branch.  Each branch, including the master<sup>1</sup>, is also a pointer to the latest revision in it's history.

Clear as mud? Let's look at an example using an image from the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/doc), that will hopefully clarify things somewhat.<sup>2</sup>

[image: Simple Git Tree]

In this diagram we have a relatively simple repository with 4 commits.  `98ca9` is the root.  There are two branches, master and testing.  The master branch is at commit `f30ab` while the testing branch is at `87ab2`. We are currently working in the master branch, so the HEAD is pointing to the master branch.  The history for the branches in our sample repository are (from newest to oldest):

```
testing:  87ab2 -> f30ab -> 34ac2 -> 98ca9
 master:           f30ab -> 34ac2 -> 98ca9
```

From this we can see that the two branches are the same starting at `f30ab`, so we can also say that testing was branches at that commit.

The Pro Git book goes into a lot more detail, and it's definitely worth a read.

Now we can address--

#### The Specific Question

Fancifying the diagram we get:

[image: Fancy like a pinky up drinking tea.]

> Is commit D a member of both branches or can we clearly decide whether it belongs to branch-A or branch-B?

Knowing what we now know, we can see that commit D is a member of both chains leading from the branch pointers to the root. Therefore we can say that D is a member of *both* branches.

> Which branch started at E, which one at B?

Both branch-A and branch-B originate from the master branch at B, and diverge from each other at E. Git itself doesn't distinguish which branch owns E. At their core, the branches are just the chain of commits from newest to oldest ending up at the root.

---

*<sup>1</sup>Fun Fact: The master branch is just an ordinary branch. It is no different from any other branch.*

*<sup>2</sup>The Pro Git book is licensed with the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.*

Comment: I thought that you were being clever and made up "fancify", but it turns out that [it's actually a real word](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fancify). Someone should tell Google that, because right now Chrome is telling me that it's misspelled `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake - While we're at it Mozilla too.  Firefox gave me the angry red squiggles.

Comment: +1, but... "The HEAD is a special pointer to the newest commit in the currently active branch": no (not always), HEAD is  the "symbolic name for the currently checked out commit" (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5772882/6309) I referred to it before as "current commit": http://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309

Comment: @VonC - Its a simplification to be sure, but detached heads isn't necessary to answer the two questions posed by the OP, and the docs make the same simplification when talking about branches. This wasn't meant to be an in depth architectural overview. I may decide to add another footnote, but I'm going to leave it as is for now.