# Which Branch Am I From?

Tags: git

Suppose we are at a *master* branch with 2 commits: *c111* and *c222*; *c222* is the latest commit. Now, we create a new *second* branch by `git checkout -b second`; then keep working on *second*.

How do we find out that *second* was actually branched from *master* at *c222*? I understand that *second* will inherit both commits (*c111* and *c222* from *master*).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the parent branch of a branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-branch)

Comment: See also [Find which branch is used to create current branch in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665780/find-which-branch-is-used-to-create-current-branch-in-git) and [Branch length: where does a branch start in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581026/branch-length-where-does-a-branch-start-in-git).

Comment: See also [Finding a branch point with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git).

Answer (score 2):

Try`git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate`, which prints out the git log as graph, containing the branch inheriting information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `git merge-base A B` [git merge-base](http://csurs.csr.uky.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?git-merge-base)

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git) might help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a good way to do this from the git command line tool, but I like using [tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/)

Edit: It is easier to remember than `git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate` and also prettier! But yeah, you do have to install one additional tool.