# Quickest way to find the initial creation of a branch in git

Tags: git, commit, git-branch, git-commit

What is a quick way to find the initial creation of a branch in git?

I want to run it with a diff on HEAD

Comment: See also [Branch length: where does a branch start in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581026/branch-length-where-does-a-branch-start-in-git). Git does not preserve when branches were created. All branches start at the initial root commit.

Comment: Possible dupes: [Find the parent branch of a branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-branch) and also
[Finding what branch a commit came from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-commit-came-from)

Comment: Original poster: you might want to edit your question to be more specific about what you're trying to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What git is really tracking is the point of divergence between the sources, so you will not necessarily, have the actual creation point of the branch available. Lots of things like merges, rebases, cherry-picks, etc will lose it.

So, unfortunately, there is no easy solution. I recommend using a GUI to examine the tree (I like GitX-dev on the mac)