# Git branch keeps moving its tip

Tags: git

In a group-shared Git repo, I had this repo structure:

```
      o---o---o---o  branch2
     /
o---o---o---o---o master
 \
  o---o---o  branch1
```

After aligning it with git flow approach, it became this:

```
      o---o---o---o  maintenance/branch2
     /  c1
o---o---o---o---o develop
 \       \
  \       o---o---o  master
   \
    o---o---o  maintenance/branch1
```

So, the 3 branches were renamed:

- branch1 -> maintenance/branch1
- branch2 -> maintenance/branch2
- master -> develop

And a new branch `master` was created from commit `c1`.

Changes were pushed on remote and pulled (with prune) on all clients.

Everything was fine, but after some time, after a fetch, the `master` tip on remote "moves" back to the old tip (same as `develop`).

I have done (locally and on remote):

```
git gc --prune="0 days"
git gc --prune=now
git fsck --full
```

Then, I again delete `master` from remote, push my local `master` (created from `c1`) and everything looks good. I even do a clone to new folder and it comes correctly -- showing new branch structure.

But after some hours/day, `master` is again "reverted" on the remote!

Remote `git reflog` shows absolutely nothing (as there were no pushes in the meantime and gc was run a day ago).

**Any ideas why the branch keeps moving its tip on the remote?**

NB. remote `HEAD` points to `develop`.

NB2. this is how I renamed the branches:

```
git checkout ${ori}
git branch -m ${ori} ${new}
git push origin :${ori}
git push --set-upstream origin ${new}
```

Comment: Bare repositories (those that accept pushes) usually have reflogs turned off.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3876206/1256452

Comment: @torek it hasn't reflog turned off. I know this as there is no config for it and b/c I was looking at it 2 days ago (before the `gc` command).

Comment: What does running `git branch -vv` show? Is the local develops tracking the wrong branch?

Comment: @BeaverusIV the local repo (with `master` changes not pulled) shows the correct comment (from `c1`), but on the remote the `master` branch has the comment same as the `develop`.

Comment: I was more thinking that each line like such: `update_manifest     fea8a74 [origin/update_manifest] Update manifest with reporting files` has the same local branch name and origin/xxx branch name. Also, are multiple people currently using this repo? Could it be someone else's actions reverting your changes by not fetching and being up to date with remote?

Comment: @BeaverusIV that is what I thought first (that someone else keeps pushing a merge), but aparently noone is.

Comment: "After some hours/day" the next step if everything is tracking right is to find out exactly when it is happening. Does it happen right after anyone pushes to remote? Does it happen only after a branch merge?

Comment: No one touches the repo and it happens. The only thing that comes to mind it to temporarily rename the remote directory and see if it will happen also.

Comment: Yeah, move it on the server so that anything that might be referencing it won't find it. See if it changes. Something is triggering it somewhere.

Comment: As I suspected, after renaming the git repo dir on the remote, the problem didn't occur again even though the few of us worked on it as usual. My suspicion is on some forgotten tooling working in background and reverting the change.